# On the use of "on" within "he goaded her on to more daring revelations"

Tags: meaning

According to the ODE, to goad means:

> provoke or annoy (someone) so as to stimulate an action or reaction.

Yet, I find it quite difficult to understand its meaning within:

> He **goaded** her **on** to more daring revelations.

Does this sentence mean:

> He provoked (goaded) her with more daring revelations.

? if so, is the "**on**" above unnecessary?

Comment: No, it does not mean the same thing as *with*. But you can certainly drop the *on* and have it mean the same thing. (It just provides emphasis.)

Comment: The "daring revelations" are not *used* to goad, but are the *result* of the goading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He goaded her **on to** more daring revelations.

**That implies there had already been revelations and these ones would be additional ones.**

to spur on, to goad on [to more things] to additional [noun]

Now, goading can be carried out many ways:

He goaded me with sweets when he knew I shouldn't be eating them.

The method can be "with x".

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the **on** in this case is an abbreviation of **onward**. In this form, the sentence becomes more clear:

> He goaded her **onward** to more daring revelations.

The implication is that she has already revealed something. He is provoking her into speaking further.